# How to implement auto logout functionality if a user logs out and then logs in before previous setTimeout ends?

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to implement an auto-logout functionality. I am implementing auto-logout using setTimeout.
Here is the code:

```
const onSubmitHandler = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log(emailId);
        console.log(password);


        axios.post('http://localhost:8080/login', { emailId, password })
            .then(response => {
                console.log(response);
                localStorage.setItem('token', response.data.token);
                axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = response.data.token;
                
                setTimeout(() => {
                    localStorage.removeItem('token');
                    axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = null;
                    navigate('/');
                }, 60000);
                
               navigate('/');
            })
            .catch(err => {
                console.log(err.response.data.message);
                if (err.response.status === 500) {
                    navigate('/500');
                }

                setError(err.response.data.message);

            })


    }
```

The problem I am facing with my current implementation is that when I `log in` to my web app and then `log out` before `auto-logout(i.e before setTimeout part fires)` then again `log in`. Now when I stay I get navigated to `"/" twice`.

This means that the previous `log in`  setTimeout did not die when I logged out manually.

Please guide me on how the previous setTimeout could be stopped once a new setTimeout starts, also let me know I more information is needed.

Comment: Cancel the previous timeout.

Comment: @catgirlkelly The previous timeout could be canceled when the previous token is not equal to the current token. I tried saving the previous token in the state but it didn't work. Please check the code I have added as an edit.

Comment: i never seen someone depending on timers to authenticate users, till now.
Anyone will tell this really bad practice and will lead to UB.

Comment: @bogdanoff I am not using a timer to authenticate but to auto log out a user

Comment: you are using setTimeout to logout user after certain amount of time instead of depending on auth token maxage which will expire after that time and once token expires users will be automatically unauthorized (if have programmed backend properly).

Answer (score 0):

I saved the old token and the new token in the local storage. I also save the setTimeout in the local storage. The old token is used to determine if a new login has been made before the token expiration time and setTimeout is stored in the local storage to delete the previous setTimeout.

Here is my code:

```
 const onSubmitHandler = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log(emailId);
        console.log(password);
        axios.post('http://localhost:8080/login', { emailId, password })
            .then(response => {
                console.log(response);
                
                localStorage.setItem('token', response.data.token);
                axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = response.data.token;

                 if (JSON.stringify(localStorage.getItem('oldToken')) !== JSON.stringify(localStorage.getItem('token'))) {
                    
                    localStorage.setItem('oldToken', localStorage.getItem('token')); 
                     clearTimeout(localStorage.getItem('timerId'));
                   
                    const myTimeout= setTimeout(() => {
                    localStorage.removeItem('token');
                    axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = null;
                    navigate('/');
                }, 60000);

                   localStorage.setItem('timerId', myTimeout);
                 }


                
                navigate('/');
            })
            .catch(err => {
                console.log(err.response.data.message);
                if (err.response.status === 500) {
                    navigate('/500');
                }

                setError(err.response.data.message);

            })


    }
```